# Kenny stopped dying. Why?

Tags: character, south-park

In later episodes of South Park, Kenny stopped dying. Why did South Park stop killing Kenny? Just Wondering.

Comment: Because it got old.

Comment: ...you bastard!

Comment: ugh... spoilers much?

Comment: @progo was that sarcastic?

Comment: @Hellreaver: Why would it be sarcastic? This entire post, _including its title_, is a giant spoiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe so, but the show isn't exactly story-oriented

Comment: @Hellreaver: So?

Comment: @Hellreaver: it's a joke :) usually people spoil by telling that someone's going to die

Comment: @progo ah, okay. I can see the humor in it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quite simply, **[the creators grew tired of killing him off every episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_McCormick#Deaths)**.

While it was initially fun thinking up new ways for him to die, after several seasons Parker and Stone found it to be incredibly mundane. Coupled with the rising popularity of a newer character, Butters Stotch, the creators were growing very tired of Kenny and thus decided to kill Kenny permanently in season five.

The intention was to keep him dead, but they decided to bring him back at the end of season six, and further decided to not kill him off every episode.

More recently they've hinted that Kenny is immortal because his parents attended several Cthulhu-like cult meetings years earlier.

Comment: So the secret to immortality is to attend Cthulhu-like cult meetings? Good to know. I'll go add that to Lifehacks.

Comment: @BrettFromLA  Well, Kenny's parents were the ones who attended the Cthulhu meetings, and every time Kenny dies, Carol McCormick gives birth to a Kenny clone that grows up overnight.  So for the people who actually attended the Cthulhu meetings, the result isn't so rosy.

Comment: @Waxen Oh. So I need to get my parents to attend. Got it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Well, that's not even really immortality... Kenny's immortality would cease when his mom died...